# Ignored files are still visible in Commit Changes window - IntelliJ 13

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitignore, ignore, intellij-13

1. I went to:

   > File > Settings... > Version Control > Ignored Files

   and I added some files using the `+` symbol > `Apply` > `OK`
2. I pressed right click on the project folder:

   > Git > Commit Directory...

   and the ignored files are still there (Commit Changes window).

I also tried to restart IntelliJ, but there was the same behavior.

How can I really **ignore** some **files** ?

**Details:**

- IDE: IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.4
- O.S.: Windows 7
- ignored files format: XML

Comment: your files was already commited by previous commits ?

Comment: The files are in repository, but on my local machine they are changed and those changes were not committed.

Comment: I had the same issue. Ignored files still shown in the change list of the commit window, and still can be pushed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really advised to doing this, but you can use

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/*.xml
```

Excerpt from [git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html):

**--assume-unchanged**

**--no-assume-unchanged**

When these flags are specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated. Instead, these options set and unset the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths. When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, git stops checking the working tree files for possible modifications, so you need to manually unset the bit to tell git when you change the working tree file. ...

**This option can be also used as a coarse file-level mechanism to ignore uncommitted changes in tracked files (akin to what .gitignore does for untracked files)**. ...